# python operation not permitted (graphtecprint)

Tags: python, linux, file-io, usb

I'm running a python program. When it get's to these lines:
`f = open("/dev/bus/usb/007/005", "r")`

`x = fcntl.ioctl(f.fileno(), 0x84005001, '\x00' * 256)`
 It fails saying:
IOError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted
What could be causing this problem?

Comment: which one is giving the error, the first or the second line. what the traceback says?

Answer (score 1):

file system permissions?

what does ls -l /dev/bus/usb/007/005 say?

does cat /dev/bus/usb/007/005 work or does it report the same error?

Comment: output of first is:
`crw-rw-rw- 1 root lp 189, 772 24.04.2010 15:58 /dev/bus/usb/007/00`

the cat command prints some weird chars to the terminal.

Comment: Also, running as root outputs the same thing.

Comment: then probably the ioctl is failing. I have no deeper knowledge of usb devices and ioctls.


The ioctl you are trying to do could be

 - only allowed by root
 - wrong magic number
 - only works on files opened r/w

Sorry I can only guess

Answer (score 0):

The third argument to `fcntl.ioctl`, as documented [here](http://docs.python.org/library/fcntl.html#fcntl.ioctl), should be either a 1024-byte string (not just 256), or, better, a possibly even-larger writeable [buffer](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html?highlight=buffer#buffer) -- the underlying object could be an [array.array](http://docs.python.org/library/array.html?highlight=array.array#array.array) of bytes.  Unfortunately you need to know in advance how much space the result will need, but you can play it safe with a few KB (that ioctl seems to be the "get device id" code, but I'm not sure what the max result length could be).